# Problem converting GDL90 CRC code to Python

Tags: python, crc

In the GDL90 specification there is a piece of C code that can be used to develop a CRC-16 checksum table. I have converted this to Python 3.8, but the result is nonsense, the table values grow monotonically to more than 16 bits. What am I doing wrong?

GDL90  Code:

```
void crcInit( void )
{
    unsigned int i, bitctr, crc;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        crc = (i << 8);
        for (bitctr = 0; bitctr < 8; bitctr++)
        {
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ ((crc & 0x8000) ? 0x1021 : 0);
        }
        Crc16Table[i] = crc;
    }
}
```

My translation:

```
crcTable = []
for i in range(256):
    crc = (i << 8)
    for bitctr in range(8):
        # original line crc = (crc << 1) ^ ((crc & 0x8000) ? 0x1021 : 0)
        if (crc & 0x8000):
            val = 0x1021
        else:
            val = 0
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ val
    crcTable.append(hex(crc))
```

Comment: Why are you using `hex(crc)`? Just save `crc & 0xffff` Or `crc & 0xff`

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use `hex(crc)` - that converts the value to a string. You din’t include the c definition of Crc16Table - I guess you want to save either 8-bit or 16-bit values into the table so either save `crc&0xff` Or `crc&0xffff`

Comment: `crc & 0xffff`.

Comment: Thanks balmy, I need 16-bit, and with your suggestion that's what I get. Now lets see if it delivers the expected results!

Comment: Have you compared the crcTable from Python with Crc16Table from C?